# Jquery Plugin not working how I want it to

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using TinyColor Jquery plugin.

When you click on the hex code at the top or type in a color to the input it changes the colors in circles.

I want to be able to click on the Hex with the circles and have it load based on that Hex but it is not working...Anything will help!

```
    function colorChange(o) {
    function n(o) {
        return $.map(o, function(o) {
            return '<span style="background:' + o.toHexString() + ';" class="hextext"><a href="#"  >' + o.toHexString() + "</a></span>"
        }).join("")
    }
    var t = tinycolor(o),
        r = ["hex:  " + t.toHexString()].join("\n");
    $("#code-output").text(r).css("border-color", t.toHexString());
    var i = $("#filter-output").toggleClass("invisible", !t.isValid()),
        e = t.monochromatic();
    i.find("#mono").html(n(e));
    var a = t.analogous();
    i.find("#analogous").html(n(a))
}
$(function() {
    $(".color").bind("keyup change", function() {
        colorChange($(this).val())
    }), $("a").click(function() {
        return $(".color").val($(this).text()).trigger("change"), !1
    }), colorChange({
        r: 25,
        g: 50,
        b: 100
    })
});
```

http://codepen.io/andrewp/pen/KwZbPW

Comment: Where is this function `colorChange`?

Comment: Its in the other piece of script in the codepen example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the event you have already defined for the `anchor` , you also need to address the new events for anchor tags as the element in your so called circles are dynamically generated. So,

```
 //For AnchorUse these two event handler and it will work as required,
 $(document).on("click","a",function() {        
        $(".color").val($(this).text()).trigger('change');
        return false;
  });
  
 //For Color patches 
 $(document).on("click",".hextext",function() {  
        $(".color").val($(this).children("a").text()).trigger('change');
        return false;
    });
```

**Note:**

The `click` event you have designated for the anchor will not work for the dynamically created anchor. To tackle that you need to [Understand & Use Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

#### See the [Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNQOMw)